# How to access two pages with the same url part in SilverStripe template

Tags: silverstripe

does anybody know how to solve following ?

I have in SilverStripe two different pages with the same name and url, but in different hierarchy structure.

*www.example.com/xyz/url-part*

*www.example.com/abc/url-part*

I would like to access this pages in template as

```
<% with Page('url-part') %>
    $Title
<% end_with %>
```

but I'm not able to differ these two pages. Any ideas?

Comment: Which one do you want to show? Always the same or depending on where you are one or the other? I guess you'll have to write your own getter in your Page_Controller to get the Page DO.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I always want to show it on the parent page. So on xyz or abc I want to show the child of current one with url 'url-part'.

Comment: You still can do it in template.
 
 <% loop $Children.filter(URLSegment, "url-part") %>
  $Me
 <% end_loop %>

Anyway if URL-Segment is editable per CMS I recommend to filter against ID or what ever.

Comment: Thanks  munomono, that's how I done it finally.  Let's add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we go @MartinRázus :)

```
<% loop $Children.filter(URLSegment, "url-part") %>$Title<% end_loop %>
```